# Spark: what UUID version is used in the built-in uuid() function implementation?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

SparkSQL has the [`uuid()` SQL built-in function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#uuid).

However, neither the documentation states the UUID version nor I could find the source code, after a quick search.

I can assume that it is likely to be UUID V4.

**What is the version used to implement it?**

Thanks.

---

**Bonus question:** Where is it implemented in the source code? I would be happy to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but when i am running this sample select (SELECT uuid();) in query details i can see this

```
(2) Project [codegen id : 1]
Output [1]: [uuid(Some(-1736932742140897221)) AS uuid()#8]
Input: []
```

In Spark repo UUID expression is defined in [`misc.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.3/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/misc.scala#L191)

```
  :
  usage = """_FUNC_() - Returns an universally unique identifier (UUID) string. The value is returned as a canonical UUID 36-character string.""",
  examples = """
    Examples:
      > SELECT _FUNC_();
       46707d92-02f4-4817-8116-a4c3b23e6266
  """,
  note = """
    The function is non-deterministic.
  """,
  since = "2.3.0",
  group = "misc_funcs")
  :
```

and is using [`RandomUUIDGenerator`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.3/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/RandomUUIDGenerator.scala)

...which provides further details about the algorithm:

> - For the algorithm, see RFC 4122: A Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) URN Namespace,  * section 4.4 "Algorithms for Creating a UUID
>   from Truly Random or Pseudo-Random Numbers".

And from the [above document](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) we can see that Spark's implementation complies to UUID v4:

> 4.4.  Algorithms for Creating a UUID from Truly Random or
> Pseudo-Random Numbers
>
> The version 4 UUID is meant for generating UUIDs from truly-random
> or    pseudo-random numbers.
>
> The algorithm is as follows:
>
> o  Set the two most significant bits (bits 6 and 7) of the
> clock_seq_hi_and_reserved to zero and one, respectively.
>
> o  Set the four most significant bits (bits 12 through 15) of the
> time_hi_and_version field to the 4-bit version number from
> Section 4.1.3.
>
> o  Set all the other bits to randomly (or pseudo-randomly) chosen
> values.